# VBA Excel display message box for all users of a shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared workbook that is updated with new data throughout the day. I'd like to be able to run a macro that will accept some text. for example: " Workbook has been updated" and display this in a message box for each user of the shared workbook. Is this possible?

I do not have an option to in share the workbook in case that matters.

Comment: Do you have a list of users you want to notify, or do you need to collect those from users who access the Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already know this, but shared workbooks do not maintain a "connection" to the shared file per se. What happens is that each user opens a copy of the file into their own computer's memory, and then only when they save will Excel check their local copy against the file. It is only at that point that any changes are known.

When the user saves the workbook, then if other people's changes have been made in the meantime, Excel's native functionality already pops up a message saying that the workbook has been updated by other users.

If, on the other hand, you're looking for a function which would automatically pop up a message immediately when other users save the file, then it can't be done (because, as I said above, there is no live connection present). The closest thing to that would be to ensure that the workbook was saved regularly via an Application.Ontime recurring event.